# UITextView's Phone Number Detection causes UITableView to crash

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, phone-number

I have a straightforward UITableView whose cells each contain a UITextView to display a phone number.  If I scroll the table slowly, everything works as expected and the phone numbers turn into links.  If I scroll the table quickly, it crashes.  Similarly, if I turn off Phone Number Detection for the text view, it works normally.  Does anyone know what I can do to make Phone Number Detection work properly in a table view?

Comment: More code, please.  This is a shot in the dark, but I have had text views cause crashes when creating them from a thread other than the main thread, for example after concluding an asynchronous data load.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to look down into your code on how did you put the UITextView on the UITableViewCell.

And also, you might need to reuse your cells.

Comment: Cells are being reused. Can you be more specific about what I should be looking at?

Comment: how are you creating the uitextview in each cell? can you post your tableview methods

Comment: It might be helpful if you post some of your codes. Or just give us an idea how did you create the UITextView's